Hazelcast management is giving below error while accessing it from chrome even though the service is running fine
Backend down or bad FE build. Could not load mcbootstrap.js".
Can see it's trying to invoke below api while hitting the hazelcast management VIP and it's is failing with 404
Request URL:
https://VIP/mcbootstrap.js
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
404 Not Found
Am using the below docker image in K8 and passing extra variables.
"-DMC_CONTEXT_PATH=/mancenter -Dhazelcast.mc.tls.enabled=false"
hazelcast/management-center:5.4.0

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could you please provide more details about you k8s setup, so I can reproduce this one?
Also, there are few inconsistencies I see in you extra variables:

-DMC_CONTEXT_PATH=/mancenter seems to be invalid. MC_CONTEXT_PATH is environment variable name, for system property you have to use -Dhazelcast.mc.contextPath. See https://docs.hazelcast.com/management-center/5.4/deploy-manage/system-properties#management-center-configuration
-Dhazelcast.mc.tls.enabled=false. You disabled TLS for MC but you are trying to reach MC via https://. Is there reverse proxy before MC with TLS enabled?


note: if you think a question needs more detail/clarity, you are discouraged from answering it until that detail/clarity is added. see [answer].
